# Global Variable or Inaccesible link through direct URL

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to create a CodeIgniter page where in the `page.com/passenger` view you can see all the places visited by the logged `passenger`. In that view you can click a specific `place` and redirect you to `page.com/passenger/photos` to show a Bootstrap Carousel with the selected place's photos (you can also view all the photos in this view, including the other place's photos).

**The problem is** that I don't know if I should store the `places` with their respective `photos` in a global variable, because an user can access directly to `page.com/passenger/photos` and no `places` would have been provided to the `photos($places)` method in the Passenger Controller and get the following error

> Too few arguments to function Passenger::photos().

But if I store the `places` and their `photos` in a global variable array i can access them directly in the photos() Controller and the error should not be displayed.

Comment: and how you passe the places if a user click in a specific place to view the photos?

Comment: @SoufianeLamnizeh I already have the places in page.com/passenger, imported from Passengers_model

Comment: but how you can get photos of a place? can you give me a example of the routes and the function in the controler

Comment: `global` variables, despite being discouraged, do not maintain their state across instances. a global variable set to `foo` in one page, will be empty in another page if it isn't set again. if you need data to be persistent across pages you need to store it somewhere (database, session, cookie, query string). aside from your question, you should declare methods with get parameters as `function photos($getparam = null)` to avoid too few arguments. then you should check that the variable isn't null.